# echo & if else in .hql (HIVE) file

Tags: bash, unix, hive

How to execute echo & if else in .hql(hive) file?

I am able to execute echo like the below:

```
!echo "test";
```

But not able to execute 'if-else' like the below.

```
!if [ 1=1] then
!echo "if is working"
!else
!echo "not working"
!fi
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think `!` can be used on a single command. To run multi-line scripts put it in a shell script and run it.

```
Unix_prompt$ cat script.sh
if [ 1=1 ] 
then
echo "if is working"
else
echo "not working"
fi


HIVE> !./script.sh;
```

Comment: I did the same. Not running it as a single command. I kept the code in a shell script and saved with extension .hql file and running it. But no luck with if-else.

Comment: I think problem is not with `HIVE`. your `if` condition does not have a space before `']'` also `then` should be on next line.